# Can I install Chrome on my Ubuntu Phone

Tags: google-chrome, uninstall, phone

I tried installing chrome as per instructions at http://www.howtogeek.com/203768/beginner-how-to-install-google-chrome-in-ubuntu-14.04/ using my phone's terminal.

Although it seems that it has installed successfully, I can't find it in my app drawer. Is there any way I can access the installed file?

Answer (score 1):

No, Google Chrome (nor Chromium or Firefox) is not supported on the phone image. Use of apt-get to install applications is also not supported on the phone image.

However, the standard web browser on the phone image (*webbrowser-app*) is based on the *Blink* engine which is used in Chrome/Chromium.

Comment: No, it is not. The phone images are read-only for a reason. Making the system rw, will result in system image updates not being applied, or any changes you made, being reverted upon update of the system image. Please don't suggest people to do such a thing, as it is unsupported, and is a good way to end up with a phone that won't boot or upgrade.

Comment: Things installed with apt are not guaranteed to be kept around. The amount of space in / is very small, and will fill up very quickly if you start trying to use apt. Some things are not in the archive, and so aren't even available in apt. If you want to use apt, you should create a chroot under ~/ on the phone, and install things in that chroot.

Comment: OK thanks for the info zubozrout. I can understand the reasoning why apt is not allowed. Do you know when chrome is going to be available, though? I have 4 machines and since chrome synchronises all activity, it is imperative for me to have it on the phone

Comment: When Google creates app for it on the phone, I guess. The Chrome package for Ubuntu is not suited to be run on a touch screen phone. They would really need to create an app targeting the interaction model of the phone for it to be reasonably usable on a phone. They've done this on Android of course. But Ubuntu on phones is not Android, so you can't just use that version of Chrome either.